# Why sometime response header not return text/html in perl script

Tags: perl, apache

Why sometime when request http and response header not return text/html in perl script?

- Page is randomly blank on load (white screen)
- Response headers HTTP/0.9 200 OK (white screen), but when page loads correctly – HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- No error log apache.
- When page load blank, I View page Source all tag html exist.

Comment: No error log apache, when not return text/html became white screen on browser. When I view page browser all script html exist.

Comment: Could you use more words?  I don't know what "all script html exist" means; all script and html? all the script html tags but nothing else?

Comment: Did you check the error log of your browser? If so, are there any errors present?

Comment: I mean, when white screen and I check "View page Source" all tag html exist, but response header not return text/html

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
use CGI::Carp qw[fatalsToBrowser];
```

to your program to see if you get any error messages.

Remember to comment it out again before putting the program into production.

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell without seeing the source code.  My first guess is that instead of printing

```
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
   ... rest of your page
```

you don't have the blank line after the Content-Type header.

Again, it's hard to tell without seeing your code, or seeing the exact response from the server.

Comment: Yes I already print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; this issue is randomly not return content type html